# Using Countifs with asterisks in cell

Tags: excel

I work at an online retailer which uses Excel to upload the merchandise onto our website. I wanted to use some conditional formatting to check for duplicate store titles.

The formula I used for the conditional formatting is (Q3:Q152 is where the store titles are):

=COUNTIF($Q3:$Q152,$SQ3)>1

This normally works but a few of the titles have asterisks in them. This seems to cause it to say something is a duplicate when it really isn't.

I was wondering if anyone has run into this issue before and if there is a work around. Thanks

Comment: =COUNTIFS($Q3:$Q152,$SQ3, $Q3:$Q152, ">1")

Answer (score 2):

Use Substitute to add a `~` in front of the `*`.

The `~` forces the formula to see the `*` as the literal text and not a wildcard.

```
=COUNTIF($Q3:$Q152,SUBSTITUTE($SQ3,"*","~*"))>1
```

For Example:

[image]